# htaccess rewrite all subdomain to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver, localhost

I know this question has been asked a lot but I don't know why it does not work for me :-?
this is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

this code should rewrite any link with any path including any subdomain to index.php but it doesn't.

name of the domain also should not come into htaccess since it is unknown!!!
I call this htaccess from 127.0.0.1 and many websites are supposed to be linked into localhost:

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mypc
127.0.0.1   google.com
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

here, my browser does browse google.com or example.com successfully while their subdomains such as sub1.google.com or sub1.example.com cannot be found.

index.php

```
<?php
$uri = 'http'. ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 's' : null) .'://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
print_r($uri);
?>
```

does any one know how this .htaccess code does work for subdomains too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right you are asking why `google.com` correctly loads index.php on the localhost but `sub1.google.com` etc. subdomains do not.

You cannot override subdomain DNS using the `hosts` file. To accomplish this you either need to add all the subdomains to the `hosts` file or set up a private DNS server with records for `google.com` and `*.google.com` pointing to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: you are true. I finally did that by using dnsmasq and editing /etc/dnsmasq.conf and it worked!